# Why the CKEditor 4 Angular module form field validation does not work?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ckeditor, angular-forms

Why the CKEditor 4 Angular module form field validation does not work?

My is resided in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-49fuji?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

I have tried different combination of .touched,.pristine, .valid.

However, the field does not work like another field.

That mean under the un-touch condition when I click on "save" button,

the other field error message will be shown, however, the CKEditor does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this instead what you used in demo

```
<mat-error *ngIf="(contact.touched || callTreeEditForm.submitted)  && contact.errors?.required">
      Call tree contact is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
```

You have used this

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="contact.touched && contact.invalid">
      Call tree contact is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
```

But here when user touched your ckeditor then and then you will get error validation
So you should use this condition `(contact.touched || callTreeEditForm.submitted)`  so you can get proper validation on input blur event and form submit event. 
Instead of using `contact.invalid` I preferred using this  `contact.errors?.required` because invalid will give you both required or invalid value so I think for required you can use `contact.errors?.required` instead of invalid.

Comment: The "contact.errors?.required" can be replaced by contact.hasError('required').

Comment: In fact, I have tried to bulld custom validator for ckeditor, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide me stackblitz , I will look into it.

Comment: I added the validator code to the above stackblitz, you may check now.